# Compare current row with previous row of ActiverRecord result in Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need make an option list with optgroup from the results of a query like this:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="here one of the results of query">
    <option>rest of results</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

I need something like this (or better). Example in php:

```
<?php
  $sql= "query here";
  $result=$connection->createCommand($sql)->queryAll(); //to execute the query and save in the variable result


  for ($i=1; $i <count($result) ; $i++) 
  { 
    $a = $i-1
    if ($result[$a]["optiongroup"] == $result[$i]["optiongroup"])
    {
      // agree to the optiongroup with an option
    }
    else
    {
      // close the optiongroup and starts a new option group
    }
  } 
?>
```

I have this:

Controller:

```
@componentes = Tipo.find_by_sql("SELECT t1.tip_titulo as pieza, t2.tip_id, t2.tip_titulo FROM `tipos` t1
    LEFT JOIN tipos t2 ON (t1.tip_id = t2.tip_id_padre)
    WHERE t1.tip_id_padre IN (38)")
```

In the query the results show like this:

```
pieza           tip_id  tip_titulo
Fuente de poder  41      Ventilador
Fuente de poder  42      Conector de alimentacion
Memoria Ram      43      Placa
Memoria Ram      44      Reloj
```

So the select must appear in this way:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Fuente de poder">
    <option value="41">Ventilador</option>
    <option value="42">Conector de alimentacion</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Memoria RAM">
    <option value="43">Placa</option>
    <option value="44">Reloj</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

How do I solve this with Rails 5.0.1?
greetings.

Answer (score 0):

In a regular rails app you should define a view template(that should have the name of your controller with html.erb ending, for example products.html.erb)

Then you define in products.html.erb:

```
<select>
 <optgroup label="here one of the results of query">
 <% @components.each do |component| %>
        <option value='<%= component.tip_id %>'> <%= component.tip_titulo %></option>
 <%end%>
</select>
```

So as you will see that the @componenets you defined in the controller is autometically accessible in your template view.

See the docs for Rails select http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

Comment: Hi, thx for answer but i need display the select with options group and their options when i finish the comparison like the php code and show like the final example in html

Comment: I edited my answer to give you a clue on how to do this, you should have no problem applying conditions (I see you have some condition in your php code) and rendering accordingly. Hope this helps. As you can see you basically embed ruby code in the html pretty similar to how you do it in php.

Comment: I posted my view and the problem with the optgroup, take a look

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly that @Joel_Blum, look:

```
<select class="form-control" name="tip_id_componente[]" id="tip_id_componente" multiple="multiple" size="8" style="color: black; width: 400px; ">
    <% @componentes.each do |c| %>
                                                                    <option id="<%= c.tip_id %>" value="<%= c.tip_id %>"><%= c.tip_titulo %> (<%= c.pieza %>)</option>
                                                                <%  end %>
</select>
```

but it appears without the optgroup, if i agree the optgroup like this:

```
   <select class="form-control" name="tip_id_componente[]" id="tip_id_componente" multiple="multiple" size="8" style="color: black; width: 400px; ">

 <% @componentes.each do |c| %>
<optgroup label="<%=c.pieza%>">                                                                 
<option id="<%= c.tip_id %>" value="<%= c.tip_id %>"><%= c.tip_titulo %> (<%= c.pieza %>)</option>
</optgroup>
<%  end %>
```

Then  show the html code like this:

```
<select>
<optgroup label="Fuente de poder">
<option value="41">Ventilador</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Fuente de poder">
<option value="42">COnector de alimentacion</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Memoria ram">
<option value="43">placa</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Memoria ram">
<option value="44">reloj</option>
</optgroup>
```